# 'SparkSession' object has no attribute 'sparkContext'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have Spark 2.0.0 and I am trying to run some Python examples from Spark source code.

This is the [example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/pi.py). And I was running like:

```
spark-submit pi.py 2
```

But I kept getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/docker-user/src/hellospark/src/main/python/pi.py", line 21, in <module>
    count = ss.sparkContext.parallelize(range(1, n + 1), partitions).map(f).reduce(add)
AttributeError: 'SparkSession' object has no attribute 'sparkContext'
```

I've also tested with other examples like wordcount.py, sort.py and sql.py, all of them works as expected. Anybody has met this issue before? Any comment would be super helpful.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you sure it's Spark 2.0.0? I had a similar issue, but it was just a typo `SparkContext` instead of `sparkContext`

Answer (score 0):

As @stpk mentioned, you are probably running an older spark version. For example, Spark 1.5.1 doesn't have `pyspark.sql.SparkSession` (check out the [api document](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html), but later versions have [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html).  Or use older test files.